# MS Access 2016 - Remove the title bar from a form opened as AcDialog

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi

I'm trying to replicate a Windows 10 style, full-screen modal dialog with a transparent background.  I have everything working perfectly except for the title bar.

[image: How it looks now]

I cannot get rid of it.  I've also disabled any other API subclassing for the window transparency. Borderstyle is set to None, I hid all the title bar controls.  The form is set to Popup and Modal

[image: Property Sheet from the Form]

I open it like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Modal_Full_Screen", acNormal, , , , acDialog
```

These are the API calls I make in the Form_Load event to try to get rid of it:

```
Dim lStyle As Long
SetWindowLong Me.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Me.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) And Not WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME

SetWindowPos Me.hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER
lStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
lStyle = lStyle And Not (WS_BORDER Or WS_DLGFRAME Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX Or WS_THICKFRAME Or WS_CAPTION)
Call SetWindowLong(Me.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle)
SetWindowPos Me.hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER
```

I definitely want it to stop processing and wait for input.  I know the Popup window trick where you put a loop after it opens waiting for the window to close but I'm not a fan of DoEvents, just tends to crash the stack, especially on faster machines.

If this isn't possible is there a way to disable or catch the title bar events, click and dragging it restores the window from full screen (but double clicking it does not maximize it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of things that could be going wrong here.

The first thing to check is whether the form actually has a window handle in the form load event. It may not. (It doesn't in .net's WinForms.) Set a breakpoint at the call to `SetWindowLong`, or check whether the value of `hwnd` is 0 before you make the API Calls.

The second thing to check is what the return values from those API calls actually is. [`SetWindowLong`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591.aspx) returns 0 if the function failed, unless the window style was 0 to begin with, in which case, you need to call `SetLastError(0)` before the call, and use the result of `GetLastError` to determine if the call actually failed. In pseudocode this looks like:

```
SetLastError(0)
result = SetWindowLong(...)
if result = 0:
    lastError = GetLastError()
    if lastError <> 0:
        ' Handle the error here.
    else:
        ' The window style is actually 0.
```

Also check the documentation for the the return value of [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx). (Remembering that the Windows API `BOOL` type is actually a 32 bit integer.) You should also use `GetWindowLong` to look at whether there are any window styles applied to the window yet, because if the window is still initializing, and hasn't gotten it's `WM_CREATE` yet, it may be in an undetermined state. Which leads nicely into the next thing to check.

Assuming that the form's handle is valid, and that the API calls are all succeeding, the likelihood is good that the window is resetting its window style during initialization as it applies its properties. To work around this, you could move your style customization to the form's `Activate` event which happens when the form is finally shown, and presented to the user.

If none of that works, you could subclass the window procedure, and handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618.aspx) message. In English, that's "Window Message - Non-client Hit Test". The message is sent to the window procedure by the window manager to decide which part of the window the mouse is in at any given point. To disable everything in the non-client area<sup>1</sup>, respond to the message with `HTCLIENT` which says to the window manager that the mouse is in your area of responsibility. (This message is also how you can make a form which is draggable by its background.)

If you want to eliminate the title bar entirely, and you can't manage it by setting the border style to `None` then the only other option would be to handle the `WM_NCPAINT` message, and draw the non-client area manually. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145212.aspx) for an example of how to respond to that message.

Both of the last two solutions do require quite a bit more programming work, but there are plenty of examples here on StackOverflow, and elsewhere on the web. Handling a paint would require, at a minimum, 4 or 5 additional API calls. It really depends on how important it is for you to remove the title bar from the form.

---

*<sup>1</sup> To vastly oversimplify, the non-client area represents the title bar, system menu, minimize and maximize buttons, and window border. The client area is everything else.*

Comment: I should buy you a cape, you're my hero today.  The first GetWindowLong looking up the GWL_Style was throwing an invalid index error.  My Declare for the constant was private so GWL_Style was Null.  Now it works perfectly.  Thank you very much, is was a great diagnostic lesson.